# Angular2 module similar to ngResource / $resource

Tags: angular, ngresource, ng2-resource-rest

When I take a look into Angular2 docs I can't find any REST helper module like Angular1's [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource). I find it very useful in Angular1, so I would like to have something similar in Angular2, but the only thing I can find is `'angular2/http'` which does not contain anything like that (or maybe I am not searching good enough?).

Although it is pretty much clear that it would be easy to implement a similar service on my own, is there any ready-to-use module shipped by Angular2 team or is there going to be one?

Comment: did you find any good replacement for ngResource?

Comment: Yep, ng2-resource-rest is a really good option. It is well  supported, yet comfortable and extendable.

Comment: have you find any missing thing, as compared to ng-resource?

Comment: nope, furthermore in my opinion it is a step forward compare to the original one. Just try it and you won't regret

Comment: Thanks, for your insights. I'd be using it from tomorrow onlym thanks ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few thirdparty libs that do this and tie in with RXjs.

Take a look at https://github.com/troyanskiy/ng2-resource-rest

Answer (score 2):

[`js-data-angular`](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-angular) (formerly `angular-data`) is well-engineered counterpart to ngResource in Angular 1.x and a wrapper for main package, [`js-data`](https://github.com/js-data/js-data).

As it is [shown in the examples](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-examples/tree/master/client/angular2/src), `js-data` provides framework-agnostic models and can be successfully used with Angular 2 directly.

Comment: + for the answer. Is there websockets / observables support (don't see it on their website)?

Comment: They are not built in. Observables [can be easily added](http://www.js-data.io/v3.0/docs/jsdata-observables). Websocket support is not provided, but can be added too (see [Angular 1.x examples from the issues](https://github.com/js-data/js-data/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=websocket)).

Answer (score 2):

[Restangular](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ng2-restangular) is going to `Angular2`, they already have made a good job with `AngularJS` version. May worth the try.

[Edit] I tried it on an Angular-Seed root and it didn't integrate very well during the bundle phase.
In dev mode I was easily able to send requests to the server.

The Typescript isn't really interesting since they put "any" on every object, it will need some more work to become fully production friendly.